# MS Access -- how to get other fields using a primary key

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm adding a couple fields to a form made by someone else and am having trouble getting the value in one of the fields.

The field displays a location and is called "location." But when I set a new field to =[location], it returns the primary key from the data table of locations instead of the location. When I try to get the value directly from the source, [Table]![originalLocation] returns #name?.

How can I get a field associated with a primary key? So far everything returns the value of the primary key. Thanks.

Comment: Is the form's Record Source based on a table or query?

Comment: The source is a table. You can add a new location using a query

Comment: Is `location` coming from a pick list? Did you add the field or was it there? It is likely that the field in your main table points to a sub-table of locations and that would explain why the field value is the location's ID and not it's name.

Comment: I think that is the case.